# Visual Studio Code cannot handle macro replacement correctly

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NEG(x) -x
int main (void) {
    printf ("% d\n", NEG (NEG (1)));
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio Code says that `NEG (NEG (1))` expands to `--1`.

[image: Macro Replacement by Visual Studio Code]

If Visual Studio Code were correct, this code should contain a compilation error. In fact, no error will be thrown in compilation process because the C-preprocessor cpp.exe substitutes `NEG (NEG (1))` for `- -1`.

[image: Actual Macro Replacement by C-Preprocessor]

Why cannot Visual Studio Code handle macro replacement correctly? Is this a bug of the C/C++ plugin of Visual Studio Code?

Comment: It is a defect of the Visual Studio Code, in that it is not correctly performing something we want it to do. We do not know whether it is a bug, because a bug in a program means the program deviates from its specification, and we do not know what Microsoft’s actual specification for Visual Studio Code is. For end users, it is described only vaguely. Maybe Microsoft’s internal specification is merely that Visual Studio Code perform as a helpful tool most of the time, even if it  makes mistakes sometimes. If so, then making mistakes sometimes is not a bug; it conforms to the specification.

Comment: Your macro definition is, to put it simply, pretty weird. Why define a macro that depends on whitespace to work? Furthermore, anything other than a constant or identifier will break it. `NEG(1+1)` will be `0` instead of `-2`... I wouldn't complain about VSCode not being able to deal with such a macro. Redefine it as `NEG(x) -(x)` at least.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessing does not produce a text file, or even a string of characters. It produces a list of *tokens*; whitespace is not part of this list. (A space character in a string or character literal is not whitespace; whitespace refers to spaces, tabs and newlines found between tokens.):

> (§5.1.1.2 (Translation phases), ¶1.7, emphasis added)
> White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and *translated as a translation unit*.

In a footnote in the same section, the C standard notes that:

> Source files, translation units, and translated translation units need not necessarily be stored as files, nor need there be any one-to-one correspondence between these entities and any external representation

In other words, the C standard doesn't concern itself with how the list of tokens might be visualised, nor does it guarantee that there be a visualization. Some compilers attempt to insert whitespace as required so that the output could be retokenized without loss of information; but nothing says that the external representation be a valid input to the compiler, and sometimes it isn't.

What you see as the result of preprocessing is, therefore, not the result of the preprocessing; it's just a debugging aid.